# Warning: SetOperator than SetProduct

Tags: python, optimization, warnings, prompt, pyomo

Has anyone idea what the following means:

```
[    0.00] Creating model
WARNING: Extracting subsets for Set Distances_to_I_index_1, which is a
    SetOperator other than a SetProduct.  Returning this set and not
    descending into the set operands.  To descend into this operator, specify
    'subsets(expand_all_set_operators=True)' or to suppress this warning,
    specify 'subsets(expand_all_set_operators=False)'
WARNING: Extracting subsets for Set Distances_to_I_index_1, which is a
    SetOperator other than a SetProduct.  Returning this set and not
    descending into the set operands.  To descend into this operator, specify
    'subsets(expand_all_set_operators=True)' or to suppress this warning,
    specify 'subsets(expand_all_set_operators=False)'
WARNING: Extracting subsets for Set Distances_to_I_index_1, which is a
    SetOperator other than a SetProduct.  Returning this set and not
    descending into the set operands.  To descend into this operator, specify
    'subsets(expand_all_set_operators=True)' or to suppress this warning,
    specify 'subsets(expand_all_set_operators=False)'
WARNING: Extracting subsets for Set Distances_to_I_index_1, which is a
    SetOperator other than a SetProduct.  Returning this set and not
    descending into the set operands.  To descend into this operator, specify
    'subsets(expand_all_set_operators=True)' or to suppress this warning,
    specify 'subsets(expand_all_set_operators=False)'
[    0.03] Applying solver
```

I have as a result the optimal solution but should i correct sth so the warning will dismiss?

Comment: In most cases you should always fix any warnings you see especially when they relate to model construction. Without seeing the model implementation I can't offer any hints on how to fix the warnings.

Comment: Thank you @Bethany for your answer.Here it is :

model = pyo.AbstractModel(name = "WD")
model.C = pyo.Set()
model.I = pyo.Set()
model.L = pyo.Set()
model.Incineration_Cost = pyo.Param(model.I)
model.Incineration_Capacity = pyo.Param(model.I)
model.Landfill_Capacity = pyo.Param(model.L)
model.Wastage = pyo.Param(model.C)

model.Distances_to_I = pyo.Param(model.I,model.C|model.L)

model.ReduceWasteToDebris = pyo.Param()
model.TransportationCost = pyo.Param()
model.x = pyo.Var(model.I,model.C|model.L, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals)'

Can you give me a hint about the warning?